# Slow response times Google Cloud Printer

Tags: performance, google-cloud-print

We're submitting print jobs using a script to Google Cloud print via cURL and each request seems to take anywhere around 3.5 seconds to complete the request...  Which seems like an eternity if your users are used to local printers ;)

This seems way to long for pushing a PDF to their service... As i havent seen any other issues regarding speed / response times I thought of posting it here...

What to do to debug the issue? (if there is anything to do at all?)

Comment: Some larger PDF files may take longer to process at the ePrint and Cloud Print servers, which could be causing the delay. So 3.5 seconds is still ok.

Comment: But the PDF is _really_ small: only 50kb... ? It even taks that long when passing an empty PDF document (full white page) ... ? I feel that the service is re-transforming our PDF into a new PDF to be sent to the printer... This could explain the delay but then again why re-encode the PDF in the first place... ?

Comment: do you have the most recent software installed for your current printer that you are using? and have you tried re-adding the Google Cloud Print account?

Comment: it's very possible that Google Cloud print scans for vulnerabilities and/or transforms submitted documents, which would take time regardless of how small the document

Comment: @KingReload The printers are *not* actual Cloud-ready printers: they are regular printers but this feels like it wouldn't matter since the actual cURL / web request takes 3+ seconds...

Comment: @diginoise I could understand that, but I would not expect them to do that on the wire instead of via some sort of background task... (making me wait 3sec...?)

Comment: @Gekkie I don't think they do that on the wire... PDF as format is quite flexible and extensive and **usually** requires the whole document to be present in order to render it (for example fonts used on page 1 can be at the very end of the document). You would also want to scan for the bad stuff before letting any rendering near the document from the wild, since it is the rendering / transforming which is more exploitable.